CLI game flickering
I am trying to develop a small/lightweight implementation of Tetris running in the CLI, using Python. Currently, I am using a print() for each frame update, just after os.system('cls') to clear the terminal.
The problem with this approach is heavy flickering which makes the game very difficult to look at.
Would you have any suggestions of things I should try to improve this?
Here is the Github repo of the project (the main script is not very long): https://github.com/TheoFABIEN/CLI-Tetris

Using print and cls for a game will probably always cause some flickering. I guess you would be better off using something like curses and additionally looking into partial redraws

Is it available on windows ?

I think there is windows-curses but haven't used it
pip install windows-curses

I don't know much about how this works, but I had the same problem recently and if you use print("\033[H", end="") as the screen clearing code it does not flicker, hope this helps!
